# Hyper-terminal: How to get Ctrl R working for reverse history search (and other Ctrl key bindings)

Tags: key-bindings, keymapping, hyperterminal

This [issue](https://github.com/zeit/hyper/issues/1720) has already been posted in Github and it was closed that it was merged in this [pull request](https://github.com/zeit/hyper/pull/1876). But I still can't get the shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> working which I use very often :( It get's registered as `Ctrl` `R` as shown below:

[image]

I'm on Windows with Hyper version 3.0.2 stable, I tried a 3.0.1 as well, but no luck.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: The reason this happens is because `cmd` in Windows doesn't support that. You would see the same exact result `^R` when you open cmd and press `Ctrl R`. If you can make hyper use `PowerShell` then you should be fine.

Comment: @vinnybad I started using `Windows Terminal` and it satisfies my needs :)